# Сделать запись в локальном файле js WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

На вордпресс есть обработчик нажатия кнопки на js. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку шла запись в файл. Никак не могу сделать, пока вот так написал, но толку нет. Не судите строго, в js только первые шаги...

И сразу вопрос, если это js файл, могу ли я подтянуть сюда переменную способами php?

```js
$('.howcost-btn').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   fs=require("fs")
   fs.writeFileSync("text.txt", "my text",  "ascii")

   $('#modal-container').addClass('active');

   $('#howcost-form').addClass('active');

   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Вам нужно разобраться, что такое ajax https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0):

Клиентский js не может работать с файловой системой. В вашем случае только php

Comment: как быть, если обработки кнопки идет js, я ведь не смогу php объяснить куда и чего отправлять? или это возможно?

Comment: AJAXом разве что

Comment: подскажите в какую сторону смотреть хоть. нужно полчается переделать обработчик кнопки под AJAX?

Comment: на сервере должен быть код который принимает данные на запись. к примеру на php или даже на node написать( добавить) api которое будет сохранять данные полученные от клиентской части. НО сомнительно хранить данные в файле если для этого уже есть БД =) А вообщем то зависит от цели. Да и к тому же зависит от того где вы хотите сохранить файл. на сервере или на клиенте.

Comment: у меня есть кнопка,обработка кнопки на js реализована. сама кнопка вызывает форму обратной связи.  мну нужно чтоб при нажатии на кнопку, записывалась ссылка на товар и отправлялась на имеил, в бд, в файл. хоть куда-то)